# Jenssegers / select('column') returns more columns than the one specified in the select

Tags: mongodb-query, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

I have the following issue with jenssegers query builder (I'm a new user):

```
print_r(DB::table($tablename)->where('_id',$_id)->select($table_structure_record['field'])->get());
```

returns me more than one column, despite only one column is specified in the select statement:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object ( [oid] => 5780b81d93f7fb0e00d0f252 ) [collection] => structure ) )
```

My expected result would be only ([collection] => structure) , I don't understand why i also get "[_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object ( [oid] => 5780b81d93f7fb0e00d0f252 )"

Can someone help me ? Despite many searches, it seems select statement is supposed to return ONLY the columns specified, not any other !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDb always returns the _id field unless you specifically set it not to while making the request([MongoDb Limit Fields to Return from Query Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-field)).

You can try using project instead.Then it will be something like this:

```
DB::table($tablename)->where('_id',$_id)->project([$table_structure_record['field'] => 1, "_id" => 0])->get());
```